# Эпитет — это что угодно?

Tags: untagged

Скажите, существует ли вообще "не эпитет"? Ведь любое прилагательное можно охарактеризовать как яркое, эмоциональное, оценочное, когда речь идет о человеке, но в одном случае почему-то слово считают эпитетом, а в другом нет. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему, например, `"трусливая девочка"` — это не эпитет.

Answer (score 0):

Есть элементарная подсказка для понимания сути эпитета. Эпитет обычно выражается прилагательным в переносном значении. Золотые часы - обычное определение, а золотое сердце- эпитет. Исходя из этого, можно с уверенностью сказать, что в словосочетании "трусливая  девочка" присутствует обычное определение

Comment: Эпитетом может быть прилагательное и в прямом значении.

Comment: Не слышал о таком. Может, приведете пример?

Comment: Отдать сердце жестокой возлюбленной.

Comment: Неубедительно. А как Вам, например, такое: "Отдать сердце грязной возлюбленной"?

Comment: В вашем примере можно обнаружить и переносное значение.